# Is it possible to colour text of specific characters in a QT combobox

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a combobox I am populating based on a selection in a tree, however it's possible the items for the combobox provided by the selection will not match up perfectly.  To account for this I am putting a '*' next to those items to indicate that it will not effect the entire selection.  I would like to change the colour of just the '*' character in the text.  I've colour coded the tree so the goal is to show which rows are causing the conflict with the combobox options.

I know with some widgets you can use HTML tags to colour text, but that does not seem to apply to comboboxes.

Is there a way to colour individual characters in combobox text?

Comment: you only want to color the asterisks that are shown in the texts shown in the QComboBox?

Comment: That's correct.